# Google script, ignoring for loop - Spreadsheet

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, runtime-error

I've been searching for scripts and stuff to look up but, seems like google api has been changed too much or I'm dumb and doesn't know how to execute old scripts and make them work.

I keep getting these errors Parsing error... Yahoew this helps to a lot. Not knowing what line. So I made my own.

```
function amountOfColors(color, range){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var orgColor = ss.getRange(color).getBackground();
var range = ss.getRange(range);

var x = 0;
Logger.log("I was here before the loop.");
for (var i; i < range.getNumRows(); i++) {
Logger.log("Entered Row loop");
for (var j; j < range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
  Logger.log("Entered Columns loop");
  var curCell = range.getCell(i, j);
  Logger.log("curCell is : " & curCell);
  if(curCell.getBackground() == orgColor) {
    Logger.log("curCell color is : " & curCell.getBackground());
    x++;
  }
}
}
Logger.log("END");
return x;
};
```

As you can see I pretty much made it log for every thing. However this is what it returns in the logfile:

```
[14-02-20 04:00:53:445 CET] I was here before the loop.
[14-02-20 04:00:53:445 CET] END
```

Not even touching my loop?

All I want this script to is to take a color from a original position and then find how many cells has that color and return it. Really simple script.

Hope someone can enlighten me on this one. I've tried to install scripts from the script gallery that does similar but they return errors too.

Here's a picture of a setup:

http://b.imgdrp.com/PCoT.PNG - I realise it says B33:B35, but even with A it doesn't work.

Comment: ok after fixing i and j to be = 1 I can get through the loops, also I've edited the spreadsheet statement to be "=amountOfColors("A35"; "A33:A35") but now it seems to not get through my if statement oO.

even tried to set the orgColor to currentColor its checking and try to pass an if statement that way but still nope.

Comment: Found my answer, but I can't add it before there's gone 8 hours, due to not having 10 reps.

Comment: Well done. Glad you found the answer. The code is google-apps-script. Also this is more of a code review question, so not such a good fit for stackoverflow. Sounds like you are making good progress.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for commenting, I'll try to use a more appropriate forum later on.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own answer in case someone would have similar problem.

```
function amountOfColors(color, range){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var orgColor = sheet.getRange(color).getBackground();
  var range = sheet.getRange(range);

  var x = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var curCellColor = range.getCell(i,j).getBackground();
      if(curCellColor == orgColor)
        x++;
    }
  }
  return x;
};
```

Other than this I changed the way I called my function:

instead of:

```
=amountOfColors("A35", "A33:A35")
```

you need to use:

```
=amountOfColors("A35"; "A33:A35")
```

As you can see semi-colon instead of comma.

My apologies for posting and fixing it so fast, seems like all I needed was that 1 extra hour to get crafty. At least hope someone might gain something from this.
If there is any questions about the code feel free to add a comment, I'll try to explain.
Best Regards Qvintus.